# Navigation Sub Menu

Tags: html, css

first a quick thank you to all who have helped me previously :)

The issue I have now is my navigation bar, when it goes to Tablet size it seems to transition the li's to the left, this also happens to my sub menu's.

My second is issue is that my sub menu don't work how them are meant to in mobile size, in mobile size the nav menu doesn't show the sub menus.

When I click on the sub menu there seems to be a transition on the li sub menu color hard to explain but you can see it on the full media size.

Thank You in advance.

```
    <!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xml:lang="en" lang="en">
<head>
    <title>title</title>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
    <meta name="description" content="" />
    <meta name="keywords" content="" />
    <meta name="robots" content="index,follow" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="styles.css" />

</head>

<body>
<div id="MainContainer"><!--Start of MainContainer-->

    <div id="Header"><!--Start of Header-->

        <div><img id="Logo"src="images/logo.png"></div>


        <nav><!--start of nav tag-->
            <span class="nav-btn"></span>
                <ul class="nav">
                    <li><a href="#">Contact Us</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Media</a>
                        <ul>
                            <li><a href="http://sermon.net/">Sermons</a></li>
                            <li><a href="#">Gallery</a></li>
                            <li><a href="#">Blah</a></li>
                        </ul>

                    </li>

                    <li><a href="#">Ministries</a>
                        <ul>
                            <li><a href="#">Evangelism</a></li>
                            <li><a href="#">Youth</a></li>
                            <li><a href="#">Newsletter</a></li>
                        </ul>
                    </li>
                    <li><a href="#">Services</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">About Us</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Home</a></li>
                </ul><!--End of nav class ul tag-->
        </nav><!--End of nav tag-->

    </div><!--End of Header-->
    <div id="share">
    <!-- SMARTADDON BEGIN --> <script type="text/javascript"> (function() { var s=document.createElement('script');s.type='text/javascript';s.async = true; s.src='http://s1.smartaddon.com/share_addon.js'; var j =document.getElementsByTagName('script')[0];j.parentNode.insertBefore(s,j); })(); </script> <div id="sa_share_bar"> <a id="sa_share_facebook" layout="icon" size="24"></a> <a id="sa_share_twitter" layout="icon" size="24"></a>  <a id="sa_share_email" layout="icon" size="24"></a> <a id="sa_share_share" layout="icon" size="24"></a> </div> <!-- SMARTADDON END -->

    </div>

        <div class="firstsection">




<div class="slideshow-container">

<div class="mySlides fade">
  <div class="numbertext"></div>
  <img src="images/verse.jpg" style="width:100%">
  <div class="text"></div>
</div>

<div class="mySlides fade">
  <div class="numbertext"></div>
  <img src="images/run.png" style="width:100%">
  <div class="text"></div>
</div>

<div class="mySlides fade">
  <div class="numbertext"></div>
  <img src="images/gill.jpg" style="width:100%">
  <div class="text"></div>
</div>

</div>
<br>

<div style="text-align:center">
  <span class="dot"></span>
  <span class="dot"></span>
  <span class="dot"></span>
</div>

<script>
var slideIndex = 0;
showSlides();

function showSlides() {
    var i;
    var slides = document.getElementsByClassName("mySlides");
    var dots = document.getElementsByClassName("dot");
    for (i = 0; i < slides.length; i++) {
       slides[i].style.display = "none";
    }
    slideIndex++;
    if (slideIndex> slides.length) {slideIndex = 1}
    for (i = 0; i < dots.length; i++) {
        dots[i].className = dots[i].className.replace(" active", "");
    }
    slides[slideIndex-1].style.display = "block";
    dots[slideIndex-1].className += " active";
    setTimeout(showSlides, 4000); // Change image every 2 seconds
}
</script>


        </div>

            <div id="WelcomeBox">
                <img id="WelcomeImage" src="images/welcome logo.png"/>
            </div>



        <div class="secondsection">

            <p>
                First Words<br><br>
                *secondsection secondsection secondsection secondsection secondsection secondsection secondsection 
                secondsection secondsection secondsection secondsection secondsection secondsection secondsection 
                secondsection secondsection secondsection secondsection secondsection secondsection secondsection 
                secondsection secondsection secondsection secondsection secondsection secondsection secondsection 
                secondsection secondsection secondsection secondsection secondsection secondsection secondsection 
                secondsection secondsection secondsection secondsection secondsection secondsection secondsection 
                secondsection secondsection secondsection secondsection secondsection secondsection secondsection 
                secondsection secondsection secondsection secondsection secondsection secondsection secondsection 
                secondsection secondsection secondsection secondsection secondsection secondsection secondsection 
            </p>
            </div>




        <div id="Footer">
        Footer Footer Footer Footer Footer<br>
        Footer Footer Footer Footer Footer<br>
        Footer Footer Footer Footer Footer<br>
        Footer Footer Footer Footer Footer<br>
        Footer Footer Footer Footer Footer<br>
        Footer Footer Footer Footer Footer<br>
        </div>

    </div><!--End of MainContainer-->


<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
$('span.nav-btn').click(function(){
    $('ul.nav').slideToggle();
})

$(window).resize(function(){
        if($(window).width() > 600){
            $('ul.nav').removeAttr('style');
    }

        })
</script>
</body>
</html>


 body{
            width:100%;
            height:100%;
            background:url(images/glasgow.jpg);
            background-position: center center;
            background-repeat:  no-repeat;
            background-attachment: fixed;
            background-size:  cover;
            background-color: #999;

 }

 *{
     padding:0px;
     margin:0px;
 }

 #MainContainer{
width:100%;
height:auto;     
 }

 #Header{
     width:100%;
     height:auto;
     position:fixed;
    right: 0;
    top: 0;
    left:0;
    z-index:2;
}

 #share{
     top:102px;
     position:fixed;
     z-index:5;
 }

 /*Top Logo*/
 #Logo
 {
    width:115px;
    height:auto;
    float:left;
    margin:15px;
    cursor:pointer;
    position: fixed;
    z-index:1;
 }


 /*Navigation ul*/
     .nav {
     width:100%;
     background:black;
     line-height:100px;
     position:fixed;
     border-bottom: 2px red solid;
}

 /*Navigation li*/
    nav .nav li{
    list-style-type: none;
    float: right;
    position:relative;  
}

#NavBar ul:after{content:"";display:block;clear:both}


 /*Navigation a*/
    nav .nav li a{
    color:white;
    text-decoration: none;
    padding:20px;
}

 /*Navigation a*/
    nav .nav li a:hover{
    color:red;
    text-decoration: none;
    padding:20px;
    background:navy;
    transition:all 0.80s;
}

/*Navigation li HOVER*/
    nav .nav li:hover{
     background:black;
     transition:all 0.80s;
}


/*hide submenu*/
    nav .nav li ul {
    width:auto;
    display: none;
}

/*Show submenu at hover*/
    nav .nav li:hover ul {
    width:auto;
    display:block;
    position:absolute;
    top:100px;
    background-color:black;
    border-bottom:2px red solid;
}

/*Make submenu vertical*/
    nav .nav li ul li{
    width:100%;
    display: block;
    float:none;
    line-height:60px;
}

 /*Navigation sub li* xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx yellow to navy*/
    nav .nav li ul li:hover{
        width:100%;
     color:red;
    text-decoration: none;

    background:yellow;
}

 /*Navigation axxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx */
    nav .nav li ul li a:hover{
        width:auto;
    color:yellow;
    text-decoration: none;
    background-color:pink;

}

.nav-btn{display:none;}

.firstsection{
    width:100%;
    min-height:600px;
    margin-top:100px;
    padding-top:50px;
    background:url(images/1.jpg);
    background-position: center center;
    background-repeat:  no-repeat;
    background-attachment: fixed;
    background-size:  cover;
    color: Black;
}

.secondsection{
        width:100%;
    min-height:500px;
    margin-top:0px;
    padding-top:50px;
    background:url(images/bk2.jpg);
    background-position: center center;
    background-repeat:  no-repeat;
    background-attachment: fixed;
    background-size:  cover;
    color: Black;
}

.firstsection p {
    width:80%;
    margin: auto;
    display:block;
}

.secondsection p 
{
    width:80%;
    margin: auto;
    display:block;
}


#WelcomeBox {
  width: 100%;
  height: 300px;
  position: relative;
}

#WelcomeImage {
  max-width: 100%;
  max-height: 200px;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  margin: auto;
}


* {box-sizing:border-box}

body {font-family: Verdana,sans-serif;}
    .mySlides {display:none}

/* Slideshow container */
.slideshow-container {
    max-width: 100%;
    position: relative;
    margin: auto;
    margin-top:50px;
    border-top:2px black solid;
    border-bottom:2px black solid;
}

/* Caption text */
.text {
    color: #f2f2f2;
    font-size: 15px;
    padding: 8px 12px;
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 8px;
    width: 100%;
    text-align: center;
}

/* Number text (1/3 etc) */
.numbertext {
    color: #f2f2f2;
    font-size: 12px;
    padding: 8px 12px;
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
}

/* The dots/bullets/indicators */
.dot {
    height: 13px;
    width: 13px;
    margin: 0 2px;
    background-color:aqua;
    border-radius: 50%;
    display: inline-block;
    transition: background-color 0.6s ease;
}

.active {
    background-color: #717171;
}

/* Fading animation */
.fade {
    -webkit-animation-name: fade;
    -webkit-animation-duration: 1.5s;
    animation-name: fade;
    animation-duration: 1.5s;
}

@-webkit-keyframes fade {
    from {opacity: .4}
    to {opacity: 1}
}

@keyframes fade {
    from {opacity: .4}
    to {opacity: 1}
}

#Footer{
    width:100%;
    background: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.6);
    color:black;
    font-weight:bold;
    border-top: 2px black solid;
    text-align:center;
}





/* media queries*/


@media only screen and (max-width: 660px)){ 

    .nav{
    text-align:left;
    display:none;   
    }

    .nav > li{
        display:block;
    }

    .nav-btn{
        display:block;
        background-color:#333;
        color:#FFF;
        font-size:40px;
        text-align:center;
        cursor:pointer;

    }

    .nav-btn:before{
        content: "Menu";
    }



}


/*TABLET*/
@media (max-width: 780px){
/*Navigation a*/
    nav .nav li a{
    padding:10px;
}


}

/*MOBILE PHONE*/
@media (max-width: 660px){
    .nav{
    text-align:left;
    display:none;   
    }

    .nav > li{
        display:block;
    }

    .nav-btn{
        display:block;
        background-color:#333;
        color:#FFF;
        font-size:40px;
        text-align:center;
        cursor:pointer;

    }

    .nav-btn:before{
        content: "Menu";
    }



}

/* On smaller screens, decrease text size */
@media only screen and (max-width: 300px) {
  .text {font-size: 11px}
}
```

Comment: Could you possibly make a JSFiddle of your issue?

Comment: I've not used JSFiddle before but i shall try  https://jsfiddle.net/huz3yjrq/

Answer (score 0):

Firstly It's to do with your padding on the hover if you were to set it to "padding: 10px;" then it would not push everything to the left.

Secondly if you add a "z-index: 100;" onto (nav .nav li ul) that will sort your issue.

z-index is basically layers on the page, so by setting it to 100 it will sit over the over content on the hover.

Bad reply i know... My first answer too!

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

The reason your links are moving to the left on hover is because you have set this media query:

```
/*TABLET*/
@media (max-width: 780px){
/*Navigation a*/
    nav .nav li a{
    padding:10px;
}
```

However you have not set a `:hover` for `padding: 10px;` so it is taking `padding: 20px;` from the previous set style, therefore adding an extra 10px padding to your links and moving them.

Add this to your media query:

```
nav .nav li a:hover {
padding:10px;
}
```

For your second problem, when your menu shrinks in size, your submenu links goes underneath the main menu links, and instead of your mouse hovering over submenu, it hovers over the main links stacked up underneath. Add `position: relative` and `z-index` to solve this problem :

```
/*Make submenu vertical*/
  nav .nav li ul li{
  width:100%;
  display: block;
  float:none;
  line-height:60px;
  position: relative; /*add this to make z-index work*/
  z-index: 10; /*give z-index so submenu goes above the main menu links*/
}
```